# Java - passing in a list of string to a hashmap's value

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am trying to set a hashmap to have key as string and a list array as value.  Is it possible?  and how do I set the list into the value?

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
foo.put("key1",{"key1_value1","key1_value2"});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("key1_value1");
list.add("key1_value2");
foo.put("key1",list);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foo.put("key", Arrays.asList("key1_val1", "key1_val2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a data structure like `ArrayList` or just an array maybe to represent the list of strings as value.

- You can use the following with a `List`;

  ```
  foo.put("key", Arrays.asList("key1_val1", "key1_val2"));
  ```

  where `foo` is of type `Map<String, List<String>>`
- Or you the following with an array;

  ```
  foo.put("key", new String[]{"key1_val1", "key1_val2"});
  ```

  where `foo` is of type `Map<String, String[]>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("value1");
list.add("value2");
foo.put("key1", list);

for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : foo.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<String> valueList = entry.getValue();

    System.out.println("key = " + key);
    for (String value : valueList) {
        System.out.println("value = " + value);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
key = key1
value = value1
value = value2
```